# C++でファイルを読み込んで、そのファイルの情報を16進数で表示する

Tags: c++, macos, windows

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    string fpath;   //  ファイルパス変数
    cout << "ファイルをドロップしてください。\n";
    cin >> fpath;   //  パス入力


    if (fpath != "")    //  受け取ったファイルか空じゃなかったら
    {
        cout << "ファイルを受け取りました。";

        FILE *fp = (FILE *)malloc(sizeof(FILE));    //  変数宣言＆メモリ確保
        fopen_s(&fp, "file.pbm", "rb");             //  ファイルを開く

        do {
            int ch = fgetc(fp);
            printf("%X ", ch);
        } while (!feof(fp));

        fclose(fp);

    }
}
```

というコードを書いたんですが、`fopen_s(&fp, "file.pbm", "rb");             //  ファイルを開く`という所でユーザから与えられた、`fpath`(ファイルパス)を与えたく
`fopen_s(&fp, fpath, "rb");`
とすると

> "std::string" から "const char *" への適切な変換関数が存在しません

というエラーが発生します。
これはどう対処するべきなんですか？

Comment: [c_str](https://cpprefjp.github.io/reference/string/basic_string/c_str.html)

Comment: C言語とC++言語は別言語と認識すべきです。質問者さんはC/C++と記述されており、BLUEPIXYさんが編集でCを削除しましたが、実際のところ質問者さんはC言語／C++言語どちらでの解決を望まれていたのでしょうか？

Comment: C++ で考えています。C++はCにオブジェクト指向などの概念を付け加えた言語じゃないんですか？
そんなにも、変わるんですか？

Comment: @長谷川諒 多くの人がC++はCの上位互換であると思っていてそのようなつもりでプログラムを作成し大抵の場合はそれで期待するように動作もしますが、実際にはC++とCでは動作の異なる部分が多数ある（つまり互換性がない部分がある）ので上位互換ではありませんのでそのように使用することはできません。別物と考える必要があります。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

コメントにも書きましたがC言語とC++言語を区別して考える必要があります。C++言語の`std::string`をC言語の`fopen_s`に渡したために齟齬が生じています。ここでC++言語でファイルを扱う型としては[`std::ifstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream)が用意されており、その[コンストラクタ](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/basic_ifstream)には

> ```
> basic_ifstream( const char* filename, std::ios_base::openmode mode );
> basic_ifstream( const std::string& filename, std::ios_base::openmode mode );
> ```

と`std::string`を扱うものも用意されているため悩む必要がなくなります。
C++言語で記述した場合は次のようになります。

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string fpath;
    std::cout << "ファイルをドロップしてください。" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> fpath;
    if (!fpath.empty()) {
        std::cout << "ファイルを受け取りました。" << std::endl;
        std::ifstream fin{ fpath, std::ios::binary };
        if (!fin.is_open())
            return 1;
        int ch;
        while (std::ifstream::traits_type::not_eof(ch = fin.get()))
            std::cout << std::hex << std::uppercase << ch << ' ';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

またC言語で記述した場合は次のようになります。

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char fpath[1024];
    printf("ファイルをドロップしてください。\n");
    scanf_s("%s", fpath, 1024);
    if (strcmp(fpath, "") != 0) {
        printf("ファイルを受け取りました。\n");
        FILE *fp;
        int ch;
        errno_t e = fopen_s(&fp, fpath, "rb");
        if (e != 0)
            return 1;
        while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
            printf("%X ", ch);
        fclose(fp);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 自分は **C++** を使って行きたいので、**C++** を使います。
そして、質問なんですが、`ifstream fin{ fpath, ios::binary };`でファイルを開く際、開いた情報が入る変数**fin**は変数名がfinではないといかないというふうな記事を見たんですが、本当ですか？

Comment: @長谷川諒 さん、どのような記事を読まれたのか第三者にはわかりません。Hidekiさんも指摘されていますが、尋ねたい内容を整理して新規の質問として投稿してください。

Comment: わかりました。
ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

`fopen_s`はC由来の関数でCでもC++でも使えますが、`std::string`はC++だけで使えるので`fopen_s`は直接は引数に取れません。メンバー関数`c_str()`を使ってCで扱える文字列を取得します。いくつか気になる点も一緒に修正したサンプルはこうなります。

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string fpath;   //  ファイルパス変数
    cout << "ファイルをドロップしてください。\n";
    cin >> fpath;   //  パス入力


    if (fpath != "")    //  受け取ったファイルか空じゃなかったら
    {
        cout << "ファイルを受け取りました。\n";

        FILE *fp;   //  fpにはfopen_sが値を設定するので初期化の必要はない
        errno_t e = fopen_s(&fp, fpath.c_str(), "rb"); //  ファイルを開く
        if (e != 0)
        {
            return e;
        }

        for(int ch; (ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF; )
        {
            printf("%X ", ch);
        }

        fclose(fp);

    }

    return 0;
}
```

修正した気になる点とは

- `fp`の値は`fopen_s`が設定するので、初期化してはいけない。
  元のコードだと確保したメモリが解放されないままリークしてしまいます。
- 中身が空のファイルもあり得るので、表示するデータが必ずあるとは限らない。EOFのチェックはデータを表示する前にしたほうが良い。
  元のコードだと、空のファイルの時、ないはずのデータを表示してしまいます。
- `int main()`と宣言しているので、ちゃんと戻り値を返す。

です。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。

・fopen_s　が自動でメモリを確保してくれるんですね
・string型はC++から追加されたんですか、勉強になりました。
・int main()の戻り値なんですが、特に書かなくていいという認識だたんですが、書くのと、書かないのでは、何が変わるんですか？
・EOFのチェック　について、説明していただけると助かります。
・それと、ファイルを開いた際、エラーが出た場合`e`にエラーメッセージが返ってくると思うのですが、エラーが発生（0以外）した場合returnでエラーを返していると思うのですが、これはどこに返しているのですか？

Comment: @長谷川諒 `return`については、元の質問の趣旨とは離れていると思うので、別途質問を作成するといいと思います。stack overflow は、基本がQ/A集なので、一つのエントリで複数の疑問をまとめて解決するのは、スタイルに合いません。EOFについては説明をアップデートしました。もし聞きたいこととは違っていたら、これも別途質問を作成したほうがいいと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
助かりました。

Comment: @長谷川諒 [n4567.pdf](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2015/n4567.pdf) 3.6.1 Main function p5 ... _If control reaches the end
of main without encountering a return statement, the effect is that of executing
`return 0;`_ 「main関数の最後にreturn文がなくて到達した場合、`return 0;`が(あるものとして)実行されます。」なので「書かなくていいという認識」は間違いではないです。

Comment: >BLUEPIXY さん
ありがとうございます。書かなくてもいいという事ですね。