# while文の繰り返しでどのような事を行っているのかがわからない

Tags: c++

[前回の質問で頂いた回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/36036/c%E3%81%A7%E3%83%95%E3%82%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AB%E3%82%92%E8%AA%AD%E3%81%BF%E8%BE%BC%E3%82%93%E3%81%A7-%E3%81%9D%E3%81%AE%E3%83%95%E3%82%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AB%E3%81%AE%E6%83%85%E5%A0%B1%E3%82%9216%E9%80%B2%E6%95%B0%E3%81%A7%E8%A1%A8%E7%A4%BA%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B)についての質問です。

開いたファイルデータ`fin`をおそらく表示している箇所

```
while ((ch = fin.get()) != -1)
    std::cout << std::hex << std::uppercase << ch << ' ';
```

while文なので、繰り返し何かをしていると思いますが、実際これはどのような事をしているのでしょうか？

Comment: プログラミング以前にまずは口語と文語の違いを理解してください。

Comment: 前回の質問「ファイルを開いて16進数で内容を表示する」を実現している部分なはずですよね。分からないのはロジックなのか、個々の関数レベルなのか等も詳しく書いた方がよろしいかと。

Comment: わからなかったのは、`fin.get()`で何を行っているのかと、`cout << hex << uppercase << ch << ' ';`　で何を表示しているかなので、両方です。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

分解して順に説明していきます。

> ```
> ch = fin.get()
> ```

[`ifstream::get()`](https://cpprefjp.github.io/reference/istream/basic_istream/get.html)を呼び出し変数`ch`に代入します。`ifstream::get()`はファイル終端に達した場合に`-1`を返します。

> ```
> (ch = fin.get()) != -1
> ```

これは`ch = fin.get()`実行後に`ch != -1`を評価します。つまり終端に達しない限り`true`となります。

> ```
> while ((ch = fin.get()) != -1)
> ```

つまり、終端に達するまで`ch`への代入及びループを繰り返します。
次にループする内容ですが、

> ```
> std::cout << std::hex
> ```

`std::cout`の出力形式を[`std::hex`](https://cpprefjp.github.io/reference/ios/hex.html)つまり16進表記に変更します。

> ```
> std::cout << std::hex << std::uppercase
> ```

`std::cout`の出力形式を[`std::uppercase`](https://cpprefjp.github.io/reference/ios/uppercase.html)つまり大文字に変更します。これで`printf()`の`%X`相当になります。

> ```
> std::cout << std::hex << std::uppercase << ch
> ```

`printf()`の`%X`相当の形式で`ch`変数の値を出力します。

> ```
> std::cout << std::hex << std::uppercase << ch << ' ';
> ```

続けて`' '`つまりスペースを出力します。

Comment: ・詳しく説明ありがとうございます。
`fin.get()` で一文字ずつ読み込んで、ファイルの最終にたどり着いたら、-1を返すのですか。
・１６進数で表示は`hex`
・大文字へ変換は`uppercase`で行っているんですね。

Comment: @長谷川諒 正確には`-1`ではなく、[Traits::eof()](https://cpprefjp.github.io/reference/istream/basic_istream/get.html) 具体的には、`std::istream::traits_type::eof()` で、これは`<cstdio>`の`EOF`マーカーを返すので、単に`EOF`とも書けます。（がこれだとC-styleになります）EOFは実装定義ですので（大抵の実装でそうでも）、`-1`とは限りません。また、このようなマジックナンバーは極力避けるようにします。

Comment: @長谷川諒 別のタイプの`get`を使ってEOFを使用しないで次のようにも書けます。`char ch;
        while (fin.get(ch))
            std::cout << std::hex << std::uppercase << (0xff & ch) << ' ';`

Comment: ＠BLUEPIXYさん　ありがとうございます。EOFと書く場合は、`while ((ch = fin.get()) != -EOF)`　でいいですか？

Comment: @長谷川諒 `-`はつけません。

Comment: ＠BLUEPIXYさん　すいません。タイポでした。`while ((ch = fin.get()) != EOF)`　ですね。

Comment: @BLUEPIXY  様々な書き方を教えていただきありがとうございました。とても勉強になりました。

Comment: @長谷川諒さん、質問文との対応を踏まえてこの回答については更新していませんが、[元回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/36048/4236)のコードは @BLUEPIXY さんの指摘を踏まえて更新しましたので、ご参照ください。