# includeについて

Tags: c++, preprocessor

今書いているプログラムは、関数部分と表示部分に分けていています。
関数のファイルを`fanc.h`とし表示を`main.cpp`とします。

`fanc.h`では文字列型を扱っているので`"#include <string>`と記述してあります。
`main.cpp`には、`#include "Fileinfo.h"`ヘッダーの呼び出しと、こちらでも文字列を扱うので`#include <string>`と記述しているんですが、これは二重定義になってますよね？

二重定義を防ぐために、`main.cpp`では"Fileinfo.h"がきちんと呼び出せていたら`#include <string>`を実行させないためにはどのように書けばいいですか？

---

- fanc.h

  ```
  #include <string>
  ```
- main.cpp

  ```
  #include <string>
  #include "Fileinfo.h"
  ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

結論だけ言うとstring側で二重定義に対するケアが行われておりますので、使用側では対処不要となります。
string側の実体ファイルで例として以下のような定義になっているはずです。

```
#ifndef _LIBCPP___STRING
#define _LIBCPP___STRING
...(snip)...
#endif  // _LIBCPP___STRING
```

仮に上記のようなケアが行われていないヘッダファイルをincludeする場合は
以下の様にincludeすればよいです。

```
#ifndef HOGEHOGE
#define HOGEHOGE
#include <string>
#endif /* HOGEHOGE */
```

Comment: <string>と<string.h>は別物なので両者を混同した記述は避けていただければと思います。

Comment: 質問対象はc++でしたね、cのつもりで回答してしまいました(cの場合string.hが実体ファイルかと思います。)。c++の場合実体__stringとして編集いたしました。

Comment: @H.H さん、`string`の実体が何になるかはプラットホーム依存であり、このスレッドではプラットホームが明示されていないので`__string`と断定しない方がいいかと。[別スレッド](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/36036/4236)ではos-xとwindowsを併記されてはいましたが…。

Comment: @sayuriさん 承知しました。抽象的な表現に変えようと思います。(PF依存でも二重定義部分はさすがに同様かと思いますので)

Comment: > H.Hさん　
頂いた回答の記述は、`main.cpp`への記述でいいですか？
`fanc.h`では#includeする前に`#define HOGEHOGE`とすればいいですか？

Comment: @長谷川さん <string>についていいますと<string>側で二重定義のケアが行われてますので長谷川さん側のコードでは対処不要です。

Comment: 回答欄後半の文章は「仮」の話です。仮に二重定義のケアがされていないヘッダファイルを読み込む場合は読み込み箇所すべてに`#ifndef~`を行うようにしてください。

Comment: @H.H  もし、自分で作ったヘッダファイルの場合は、記述するという事ですか？

Comment: 自分で作った場合は自分で作ったヘッダファイル内に回答欄のような二重定義のケアをするべきです。回答欄にも書きましたが「上記のようなケアが行われていないヘッダファイル」をincludeする場合には、読み込み側でケアする必要があります。

Comment: @H.H ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 2):

ヘッダーファイル自身が、自身の多重インクルードを阻止しているのが普通です。
例えば Windows のSDK のmath.hでは

```
 #ifndef _INC_MATH // もし_INC_MATHがまだ未定義なら、という意味ですね。(1)
 #define _INC_MATH // _INC_MATHを定義します(2)
  :
  ・・・math.h の中身・・・
  :
 #endif // INC_MATHが未定義の場合、のおしまい(3)
```

の様にコードされています。

このヘッダーが二回目にインクルードされた時は、
前のインクルード時に(2)で _INC_MATH が定義済みとなっているので、
(1)のディレクティブの結果が「偽」となるため、(1)～(3)の部分はスキップされるわけですね。

MSのVisual Studio では、これとほぼ同等の効果を持つ記述として、「#pragma once」というものがあります。

Comment: [`#pragma once`は多くのコンパイラーがサポート](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma_once#Portability)しています。

Answer (score 0):

string など提供されているものは2重インクルードに対処しているので、心配ありません。mainには #include を書かないという手もありますが、かえって混乱を招くかもしれません。
Fileinfo.h が2重に呼ばれたときに対処されているかの方が心配です。
もし対処していない場合は、string内部での二重定義防止策（インクルードガード）をFileinfo.h にも施すべきです。

ただし、アンダースコアで始まり大文字が続く識別子や、先頭以外でも連続するアンダースコアが含まれている識別子はシステムが使う予約語ですので使わない事をお勧めします。アンダースコアで始まるグローバル変数名も予約されています。